# In Stata, how can I programmatically specify the same ranges of axes?

Tags: graph, stata, scatter-plot

I'm trying to take control over axes of a scatterplot in Stata. Consider an example:

```
sysuse auto
twoway (scatter mpg turn), aspectratio(1)
```

I get the following graph:

[image]

I would like both of the axes to span the same range. Manually this can be achieved by:

```
twoway (scatter mpg turn), aspectratio(1) yscale(r(10 50)) xscale(r(10 50))
```

[image]

My task is now to generate series of graphs that will are part of dynamic LaTeX document so I would like to skip the step of manual adjustment of the scales. How could I implement that?

I was thinking about using Stata's locals to get a hold of min and max values from both variables somehow (I cannot tell a priori which variable/axis has largest/smallest value) but perhaps there is a smarter solution to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you know in advance which variables you are plotting, here `y` and `x`:

```
local myvars "y x" 
tokenize `myvars' 
args myy myx 
su `myy', meanonly 
local min = r(min) 
local max = r(max) 
su `myx', meanonly 
local min = min(r(min), `min') 
local max = max(r(max), `max')
```

Now use those `local`s in your call to `graph`.

That's not general -- for example, it does not support `if` or `in` qualifiers -- but it can be made more general.

Comment: Sorry for late reply - just got a chance to test your solution. Worked as a charm (shall I say - as always ;) Thanks!